# Node.js: Import .sql file and use it in query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, typescript

I'm currently using an ORM for Node, this has worked fairly well in most cases but for more complex applicants I still need to occasionally write SQL.

Luckily my ORM has a way to execute SQL queries:

```
orm.execute(`SELECT * FROM "Users"`)
```

Ideally I'd rather not write my SQL inline so I was wondering if it's possible to save my SQL query as a `.sql` file and then import it into a Javascript/Typescript file so it can be used.

```
import sql from '/my_query.sql';

orm.execute(sql)
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Use the node `fs` module to manipulate files. Its supports read/write and many more.

Comment: fs will work in development, but it won't work in production, or it will require reading from the filesystem every time a request is made which would most likely tank performance...

Comment: Cache your file read/writes then... Read your `*.sql` files into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)/[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or what ever. Become creative.

Comment: I just can't do that with serverless unfortunately :/

Comment: Hmm... Can you elaborate more, how your application design looks? I guess we speaking about 10-20 sql query (`*.sql` files), why cant you read all these files at startup, cache the content (slq queries -> see my map/set links) in memory (node.js heap) and use these query for your request? This in my opinion stateless. You just exported static queries to files. We are not speaking about the database (content).  Instead of `SELECT * ...` you use `cache["query.xyz"]` to pass to `orm.execute(...)` There is not "state". You wrote "Import sql file" therefor, I assume, you have access to the fs.

Comment: e.g: `let sql = fs.readFileSync("my_query.sql", "utf8"); orm.execute(sql)`, now you just have to cache the "sql" variable, and perform the query execution again when ever you want.

Comment: I'm speaking about `import` specifically as in js modules. Serverless Node APIs don't have an internal memory heap and they're stateless so I can't save to a cache nor can I read the filesystem at runtime.

I can create a bunch of strings from my queries at build time and export them to a JS file which can then be imported as a module, but it doesn't seem like a great solution.

Comment: Ehm. No. *Every* node app has to have a heap cache, otherwise you canse even declare a single variable... And no. You cant just "import" sql files like js/json files. The only possible solution is to use the fs module...

Comment: I'm not sure how serverless APIs are compiled, but what I do know is that I don't have a way to share state between different parts of it. ‍♂️ I was wondering if there was a trick to it, but obviously not. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your welcome. I think this sounds a litle bit like a [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Feel free to edit your question and tag me, if you want my help.